# Regex expression works, but not in JAVA regex library?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find this regular expression:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="........-....-....-....-............" ac:name="asd" ac:schema-version="."><ac:parameter ac:name="atlassian-macro-output-type">INLINE</ac:parameter><ac:plain-text-body><!\[CDATA\[[^<]*</ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
```

It works fine when I test with data in websites such as http://www.regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/, but does not on THE SAME data, when I try using it inside my Java servlet.

I had to modify the above expression, to give it as String value into a function, to this:

```
String regexExp="<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id=\"........-....-....-....-............\" ac:name=\"asd\" ac:schema-version=\".\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"atlassian-macro-output-type\">INLINE<\\/ac:parameter><ac:plain-text-body><!\\[CDATA\\[[^<]*</ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>";
```

And now, this does not work to find my matches! Can you help? All I did was to change " to \" and \[ to \\[ to make Java String accept my value!

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional backslash in the closing tag for `ac:parameter`.  i.e., `<\\/ac:parameter>` which should be removed.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String r = "<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id=\"........-....-....-....-............\" ac:name=\"asd\" ac:schema-version=\".\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"atlassian-macro-output-type\">INLINE</ac:parameter><ac:plain-text-body><!\\[CDATA\\[[^<]*</ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
    Matcher m = p.matcher("<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id=\"12345678-1234-1234-1235-123456789012\" ac:name=\"asd\" ac:schema-version=\".\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"atlassian-macro-output-type\">INLINE</ac:parameter><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[abcde</ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>");
    System.out.println(m.matches());
}
```

Comment: I wonder why my answer was downvoted. It answers the question and I even provided an example.